# Doing mosaic colour correction in ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap

I have created a mosaic dataset of two landsat 8 raster tiles.  Since there is a non uniformity and a colour variation i am not able  to do supervised classification properly.I want to do a mosaic colour correction.  After opening the Mosaic colour correction window it is greyed out and I am not able to use the function.

Should I activate any extension to use it?
Is there any other way to solve this problem other than using mosaic color correction tool.

[image: Screenshot][image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS StackExchange!  Your question is a bit unclear -  could you add some screenshots of the issue?

Comment: Does the name of the mosaic dataset appear in the Mosaic Color Correction Window? Is it currently selected? The dialog box for this tool will be greyed out if a mosaic dataset is not selected.

Comment: i have added the screenshot

Comment: Please someone help me resolve this problem.

Comment: What is your license level for ArcMap?

Comment: Let's test to make sure it's not an issue with the mosaic dataset. Try to create a new mosaic dataset using the test data provided in ArcTutor, as linked in my answer.

Comment: License type is Advanced and this problem is not occuring for all the mosaic dataset .Only with few of them it happens.

Comment: Sounds like a data issue then. Do the ones that don't work share anything in common? e.g. spaces in the name?

Answer (score 2):

Confirm that the mosaic dataset appears in the Mosaic Color Correction Window and is currently selected. The dialog box for this tool will be greyed out if a mosaic dataset is not selected.

The images below were created using Esri's tutorial for mosaic datasets: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/ex-1-creating-a-mosaic-dataset.htm.

Mosaic Dataset created but not selected:
[image]

Mosaic Dataset created and selected:
[image]

Comment: mosaic dataset is selected as shown in the screenshot but still the window is greyed out.

Answer (score 0):

Try to calculate statistic for mosaic dataset:

[image]